# Do `uintptr_t` types have a defined total ordering?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Pointers in C++ do not have a defined total ordering unless they fall within a narrow set of criteria, such as being all parts of the same subobject or array ([`expr.rel/4`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.rel#4), [`defns.order.ptr`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/defns.order.ptr)).

In fact, to even provide a basic ordering guarantee, you can't use `operator<` but instead must use `std::less` with pointers from different subobjects -- otherwise the result is not well defined behavior.
From [`comparisons.general/2`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/comparisons#general-2):

> For templates `less`, `greater`, `less_­equal`, and `greater_­equal`, the specializations for any pointer type yield a result consistent with the implementation-defined strict total order over pointers ([`defns.order.ptr`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/defns.order.ptr)).

However, in C++ we also have the (optional) type `std::uintptr_t` -- which is defined to be an `unsigned` integer value large enough to store a pointer, with the property that its capable of surviving a round-trip from `void*` to `std::uintptr_t` and back to `void*` without any loss-of-data. `unsigned` integer types also have a well-defined total-ordering -- which leads me to my question.

**Is it at all reasonable to expect that a `std::uintptr_t` from different sources have a well-defined ordering, within the definition of the C++ Abstract Machine?**

I'm not asking whether this would work in *practice*, but whether this is even feasible to assume that this is well-defined behavior (my assumption is that it is *not*)

---

As a concrete example of a potential application of this, I am interested whether something like the following is formally well-defined behavior:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto my_typeid() -> std::uintptr_t
{
    // Each 'char' has a unique address since it's static and part of 
    // each unique template instantiation
    static const char s_data = 0;

    // Use this address for an ordering system, and for identity
    return reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&s_data);
}
```

Comment: Some good reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381081/4342498) for why it might not work.

Comment: " to assume that this is well-defined behavior" Yes, it is reasonable to assume, but No, it is not well defined to order as things are laid out incrementally n memory.  Instead you will get _some_ ordering.  Note: 2 pointers with different bit patterns may point ot the same memory and may converted to the same or different `uintptr_t`.  Thus `ptr1==ptr2` does not mean `(uintptr_t)ptr1 == (uintptr_t)ptr2`.

Comment: "with the property that its capable of surviving a round-trip from void* to std::uintptr_t and back to void* without any loss-of-data." --> is more like it round trips back to an equivalent pointer, not necessarily the same bit pattern.  It would be useful to know your higher level goal.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm not sure how I follow that `ptr1==ptr2` can be true, but the `uintptr_t` version won't be. How can two pointers refer to the same object but have different bit patterns in standard C++? Are you considering the case of segmented architecture where two offsets refer to the same value? At any rate, feel free to throw that into an answer with a reference, and I'll gladly accept -- since this isn't far off from what I was expecting

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica _2 pointers with different bit patterns may point ot the same memory and may converted to the same or different `uintptr_t`_ Not sure why «different bit patterns» is necessary here. Conversion of 2 pointers with the same bit pattern to `uintptr_t` may produce 2 different integer values.

Comment: Good answers take time, short on that now.  Yes, seg:offset is one case.  An address also may have other bits in it to denote object size, write privilege, parity, ...  Common flat addressing is not the only support addressing scheme for the language.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer OP's code "an ordering system, and for identity" hints at comparing integers for identity (equivalence), hence my comments  about the equivalence as pointers do not certainly transfer to  pointers converted to integers. GTG.